# Locust Websocket Sends and receives data, but fails to repeat the action for concurrent users

Tags: python, websocket, locust

The application works on a two step process, I send data to initialize conversation via a unique wss and receives some data back. I then send another message/data to a different wss uri to await a response. This requires two websockets connection. When I simulate of a single user it works, but fails to execute multiple users. Error, socket already closed.

```
class WebsiteUser(WebsocketLocust):
  root="wss://xxxx.com/"
  uri_start_conversation = "".join([root, "/xxx?bot_integer_id=xx"])
  url = uri_start_conversation
  user_id = "some id"
  uri_send_audio = "".join([root, "messages/", user_id, "/ws/bot/xxx?bot_integer_id=xx"])
  print(uri_send_audio)

  @task
  def conversation(self):
     while True:
        recv = json.loads(self.client.recv())
        print(recv)
        question = int(recv.get("reply")[0].split("|")[0])
        send_audio_file = audio_files(index_value=question) # binary data
        loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
        asyncio.set_event_loop(loop.run_until_complete(self.speech(get_url=self.uri_send_audio, user_id=self.user_id, message=send_audio_file)))

  def on_start(self):
     websocket.enableTrace(True)
     self.client.connect(self.url)
     self.data = {
        "user_id": self.user_id,
        "message": "",
        "source": "web"
    }
     msg = json.dumps(self.data)
     self.client.send(msg)
    
  async def speech(self, get_url: str, user_id: str, message):
     Flag = True
     print(Fore.YELLOW + "[speech] wss")
     ws = create_connection(get_url) # audio wss
     print(Fore.GREEN + "[audio] wss")

     async with websockets.connect(get_url) as ws:
        while Flag:

            msg = await ws.send(message)
            #logging.info("{} audio_send".format(user_id))
            packet = await ws.recv()

            #logging.info("{} audio_response".format(user_id))
            packet = json.loads(packet)
            
            if (packet["reply"] != ["Complete"]): 
                question = int(packet.get("reply")[0].split("|")[0])
                message = audio_files(index_value=question) # binary data
            else:
                Flag = False # end of conversation
```

Comment: Using asyncio in combination with gevent is hard/may cause issues. Try to follow the example/SocketIOUser implementation more closely. Like this: https://github.com/SvenskaSpel/locust-plugins/blob/eba6b5f5fac87baddd6443d02a30a4c8f4078957/locust_plugins/users/socketio.py#L23

Comment: Oh, I noticed just now that you’re not using SocketIOUser at all. You should try it :)

Comment: @Cyberwiz much appreciated